# Custom icons for MarkerClusters in React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, react-leaflet-v3

I am trying to implement a custom icon for my markerclusters (instead of the regular circular clusters). I referred to the link and implemented as shown in the code below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-markercluster

```
import { divIcon, L, Icon } from "leaflet";

const createClusterCustomIcon = function (cluster) {
    return L.divIcon({
    html: `<span>${cluster.getChildCount()}</span>`,
    className: 'marker-cluster-custom',
    iconUrl: "leaflet/group.png",
    iconSize: [25, 25]
    });
}

<MarkerClusterGroup iconCreateFunction={createClusterCustomIcon}>
      ... My code with Markers ...
</MarkerClusterGroup>
```

But I keep getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'divIcon')

Is there a way to use custom images as icons to markerclusters? Also, is there a way to change the color of the text used to show the number of markers within a cluster? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete example update - working example is on [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/markercluster-react-custom-icon-qz0n6)

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import MarkerClusterGroup from "react-leaflet-markercluster";
import L from "leaflet";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const createClusterCustomIcon = function (cluster) {
    return L.divIcon({
      html: `<span>${cluster.getChildCount()}</span>`,
      // customMarker is the class name in the styles.css file
      className: "customMarker",
      iconSize: L.point(40, 40, true)
    });
  };

  return (
    <MapContainer
      className="markercluster-map"
      center={[51.0, 19.0]}
      zoom={4}
      maxZoom={18}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />

      <MarkerClusterGroup
        showCoverageOnHover={false}
        iconCreateFunction={createClusterCustomIcon}
      >
        <Marker position={[49.8397, 24.0297]} />
        <Marker position={[52.2297, 21.0122]} />
        <Marker position={[51.5074, -0.0901]} />
      </MarkerClusterGroup>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

File styles.css
And the most important thing you need to put `pin.png` in the `public` folder.

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.markercluster-map {
  height: 100vh;
}

.customMarker {
  background-image: url(/pin.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.customMarker span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to solve my problem. But I am trying to add an image (group.png) as the markercluster icon (just like we can add an image as the marker icon). Doing what you suggested is still giving me the same error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'divIcon') @Grzegorz T.

Comment: You have a code error. `import L from 'leaflet';` not `import {divIcon, L, Icon} from "leaflet";`

Comment: That solved my error. Thanks! 

I still want to be able to add a custom image (group.png) as the MarkerCluster icon. Right now, I have `iconUrl: "leaflet/group.png"` inside the function, but the image is not showing up as the MarkerCluster icon. How would I do that?

Comment: You have to import this graphic first: `import customMarker from './your/path/to/icon/leaflet/group.png;`  then add to L.divIcon as normal `iconUrl: customMarker` - [adding-images-fonts-and-files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Comment: I tried this. I still wasn't able to get the image as the icon for the MarkerCluster. It only shows the number of markers within the cluster. No custom graphic.

Comment: I did an update and changed the concept, added styles instead of iconUrl.

Comment: This works great, thank you! I haven't seen any solution online to change the icon for MarkerCluster and this solution solves the problem. I wish I could upvote it 10 times, but I don't have enough reputation since I'm new to Stack Overflow. But thank you.

Comment: All you need to do is to accept the solution with the code, just click the arrow up ;)
Here you have some examples of how to use the [leaflet-examples](https://github.com/tomik23/leaflet-examples)